# google map API can't set PolyLine from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I try to add coordinate to polyline but doesn't work
But when i assign it by manual it's work.

how to make its work by array.

```
var lat=[13.698090113461573,13.72771754374393,13.732881766645967,13.737967711523885];
    var lng=[100.75223565101624,100.74861466884613,100.69132804870605,100.56249350309372];

    // HERE IT DOESN"T WORK
    var poly = new Array();    
    for (var j=0;j<lat.length;j++){
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[0],lng[0])
    poly.push(pos);
    }

    // HERE IT'S WORK
    var poly = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(lat[0], lng[0]),
    new google.maps.LatLng(lat[1], lng[1]),
    new google.maps.LatLng(lat[2], lng[2]),
    new google.maps.LatLng(lat[3], lng[3])
  ];

  console.log(poly);

  var Path = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: poly,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#ff004c',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 5
  });
  Path.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that you should write the variable `j` instead of the zero numbers

```
var poly = new Array();    
for (var j=0; j<lat.length; j++) {
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[0],lng[0])
    poly.push(pos);
}
```

like this:

```
var poly = new Array();    
for (var j = 0; j<lat.length; j++) {
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[j],lng[j])
    poly.push(pos);
}
```

Comment: @Supasit Suebsunthorn, you're welcome. Don't worry it could happen to anybody

Comment: @Supasit Suebsunthorn by the way, if it answers your question can you please check this off as resolved?

Comment: dear @SantiagoHernández i customized your code and used it with my code, my fault was i was not creating array like you. your code helped me a lot to learn thank you sir cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Code is like this

```
var lat=[13.698090113461573,13.72771754374393,13.732881766645967,13.737967711523885];
    var lng=[100.75223565101624,100.74861466884613,100.69132804870605,100.56249350309372];

    // HERE IT DOESN"T WORK
    var poly = [];
    for (var j=0;j<lat.length;j++){
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[j],lng[j])
        poly.push(pos);
    }

    console.log(poly);

    var Path = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: poly,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#ff004c',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 5
    });
    Path.setMap(map);
```